# Gravar imagem em blob

Tags: php, imagem, blob

Como gravar esse código de imagem no blob?

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcKCggLDSkODQwMDRsUFR...
```

Eu peguei só um pedaço dele porque ele todo não ia caber aqui.

é só mandar o código para o campo blob no banco de dados? ou precisa fazer alguma preparação antes?

Comment: Coloca parte do código do insert ou pelos diga se é o mysqli, pdo etc

Comment: É realmente necessário salvar a imagem no banco? Não seria melhor salva-la em uma pasta física e persistir apenas o endereço da mesma?

Comment: @rray sim é Mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, apenas precisei dar um `mysql_real_escape_string` no código da imagem e mandar direto para o banco de dados mysql no campo blob